# Overlapping text over two divs centered

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to modified a code to do something a bit different but I can't get it to work. This is the code:

```
<div id="progress-bar" class="all-rounded">
<div id="progress-bar-percentage" class="all-rounded" style="width: 88%">88/100</div>
</div>
```

This renders:

[image]

Using this CSS:

```
.all-rounded {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.spacer {
    display: block;
}

#progress-bar {
    width: 100px;
    background: #cccccc;
}

#progress-bar-percentage {
    background: #3063A5;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
}
```

As you can see the text *88/100* is printed inside the inner div `progress-bar-precentage` so is centered relative to this div, the problem with this is if `progress-bar-precentage` width is very small the text will be out of place, my idea is to center it relative to the outter div `progress-bar` so it will always be in place regardless of the inner div, but i have no idea how to put the text on top and center, any ideas?

Comment: That's not CSS3, it's HTML5. And border-radius isn't CSS3?

Comment: Im sorry I meant html5, no css3.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AxDh7/)

***HTML***

```
<div id="progress-bar" class="all-rounded">
    <div id="progress-bar-percentage" class="all-rounded" style="width: 68%"><span>68/100</span></div>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```css
#progress-bar {
    width: 100px;
    background: #cccccc;
    position: relative;
}

#progress-bar-percentage {
    background: #3063A5;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    height: 20px;
}

#progress-bar-percentage span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Great use of indirect parent positioning. +1.

Comment: Great solution, Im also trying to apply your technique to this (http://jsfiddle.net/CB9AR/) other script (using the twitter bootstrap) but if I set the position relative like in your answer for some reason i loose the round effect in the inner bar... any suggestions to center also this text? Thanks!

Comment: There is a wrapper `<span>` in my solution - you're missing it in your 2nd example

Comment: Id modified the fiddle adding you span (I forgot it) the problem seems to be related with tables, http://jsfiddle.net/CB9AR/1/

Comment: Nice solution but I recommend to steer away from using `id`s for styling in case one needs to use more than one progress bar on a single page.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<div id="progress-bar" class="all-rounded">
<div id="progress-bar-percentage" class="all-rounded" style="width: 88%"></div>
<div id="progress-bar-text">88/100</div>
</div>

.all-rounded {
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.spacer {
    display: block;
}

#progress-bar {
    width: 100px;
    background: #cccccc;
    position: relative;
}

#progress-bar-percentage {
    background: #3063A5;
    padding: 5px 0px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

#progress-bar-text {
    width: 100%;
    color: #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but you break semantics by pulling the value out of the progress div.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I don't think there are any "proper semantics" for a progress bar that can be built any way you want putting together a bunch of `DIV`s/`span`s. Dawson's solution above is just as valid as Zoltan's. The only "semantic" way judging by today's state of web technology would be to use the `<progress>` tag, the problem is the lack of support from IE9 and IE8. Yaaay! I didn't have to say IE6 or IE7! :D

Comment: You can use `<progress ... ><div class="progressFallBackOuter"> ... </div></progress>` and browsers which support `<progress>` will use your semantic way and others will fall back to the 'bunch of divs' method inside it.