# How to show blocks for progressbar using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a div with 100% width on my page.
Now I need to show blocks into a `<div>` just like windows progressbar can anyone tell how I can create those blocks in the my div?

### Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: There are multiple ways to achieve that, but what did you already try?

Comment: You can also use `progress` tag .. http://jsfiddle.net/RpGwL/

Comment: Yes i can use progress tag.But i want to show xp-style progress bar blocks in my div tag in any browsers and wit any operating system.
For that background image is a best solution.

Comment: Your idea requires js. Pure CSS is impossible, because CSS is only for styling, as in how much % the image would fill the div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied @Anshuman Dwibhashi answer, but I changed the background to a piece of the image you posted. Now you just increase or decrease the percentage width of `.sub-block` to change the load bar progress.

```
<div class="main" style="border:solid;background-color:white;width:500px;height:25px;">
    <div class="sub-block" style="background:url('http://i.imgur.com/PRBmb4s.png');width:30%;height:25px;" ></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: your code would display half blocks, XP doesn't do that. It does not help OP much

Comment: but you can still increase the progress only when you know one entire block will be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aqtjQ/1/)**

**CSS**

```
  .progress-striped .bar {
    background-color: #149BDF;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-size: 40px 40px;
}
.progress .bar {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #0E90D2;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #149BDF, #0480BE);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    transition: width 0.6s ease 0s;
    width: 0;
}
.progress {
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F5F5F5, #F9F9F9);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
    height: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.progress-striped .bar {
    background-color: #149BDF;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
    background-size: 40px 40px;
}
.progress-success.progress-striped .bar, .progress-striped .bar-success {
    background-color: #62C462;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}
```

Comment: You should include an image, that thing is beautiful.

Comment: @Fags your progress bar is referenced from Bootstrap, you should relay a link to Bootstrap's page! http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6gqj/3/)**

CSS

```
.main {
    border: solid;
    background-color: white;
    width: 500px;
    height: 25px;
}
.sub-block {
    background-color: green;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 25px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="main" >
<div class="sub-block" ></div>
</div>
```

add more number of sub-blocks according to your need;

Answer (score 0):

Create an image file of that Block and use it as a background for the progress inner element. Give the background repeat-x.

For instance:

```
 background: url("Block.png") left top repeat-x transparent;
```

For further reading:

- http://css-tricks.com/css3-progress-bars/
- [Progress Bar with HTML and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190898/progress-bar-with-html-and-css)
- [Creating & Styling Progress Bar With HTML5](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-progress-bar/)

Comment: I think OP's question was if he can show progress using CSS, displaying in blocks. I think it would be impossible to do with only CSS. It requires JS.

Comment: @DanielCheung Thank you for your reply but I believe the question is how to create the blocks themselves, not how to manipulate them

Answer (score -1):

In your HTML

```
<div class="block-container">
<div class="sub-block" ></div>
<div class="sub-block" ></div>
<div class="sub-block" ></div>
.
.
.
</div>
```

In your css file

```
.block-container
{
background-color:white;
width: 500px;
height: 25px;
}

.sub-block {
background-color: green;
width: 20px;
height: 25px;
padding-left: 3px;
}
```

OR

```
<div class='fix size'>
<div style="width:100%;">
<div>
10 sub-div 10% each
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added padding. and proposed to keep the styling isolated coz in-line css is not a good practice and given the second choice as well.