# Bootstrap status bar design

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, uistatusbar, qstatusbar

I'm currently working on a form that has multiple sections. Each section has multiple questions. The number of section ranges from 5-10 and the number of questions in each sections varies as well.  All this determines based on the answers from first section.  That's a little background.  My client is asking me to replicate the design of this status bar based on the image they have provided. We are using Bootstrap and I just don't[image] know how to replicate the design exactly. The following link demos what Im able to achieve but it doesn't match the client's design. Can I get some help on this topic?!?!  https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_progressbar1&stacked=h

I have uploaded the image of the status bar which my client wants me to replicate.

Comment: Check if the following link Helps [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18267798/how-to-show-blocks-for-progressbar-using-css)

Comment: Thanks!! that helped a lot!   Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6gqj/33/)