# Implement minimal progressbar with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to implement a minimal progress-bar that fits into a cell in a table (a 2-color bar with a text on it) in HTML/CSS without Javascript?

A dynamic update of the progress bar is not needed.

Comment: Do you want the progress-bar to be dynamic? As in move along as some process is run?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Progress Bar with HTML and CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190898/progress-bar-with-html-and-css)

Comment: This jsFiddle may be of help to you: http://jsfiddle.net/jenniferperrin/j4d87/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adjust to your needs: (color, width)
Loaded percentage is inline style.

```
<div class="progress-bar">
  <span class="progress" style="width: 20%;"></span>
  <span class="text">Loading...</span>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.progress-bar{
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 24px;
  background: #bdc3c7;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: "Arial";
}
.progress-bar .progress{
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #2ecc71;
}
.progress-bar .text{
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 24px;
  vertical-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need javascript to implement dynamic behavior on a page (e.g., if you want to update the progress bar)

of course, you could always try using a META tag in the HEAD to periodically refresh the entire page, and update the progress bar on the server side, like so:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15">
```

*(I'm assuming that by "implement" you mean getting the progress bar to display the current progress)*

EDIT:
HTML5 includes a new [progress tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_progress.asp):

```
<progress value="10" max="100"></progress>
```

Comment: The progress won't change for days in my use-case, so I just display a fixed value.