# HTML and CSS progress bar

Tags: html, css, statusbar

I want to create a progress bar like in the below image:

[Progress Bar - Image](http://studio.webydo.com/siteManager/siteManager.asmx/GetWidgetCodeHtml?sProtocolType=51554b53484b61433561364e5a4755736e544d2b74773d3d&pageName=panel&pageType=inner&controlid=Widget59)

No idea how to create it.

Would you please give me some help about creating this progress bar?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Progress Bar with HTML and CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190898/progress-bar-with-html-and-css)

Comment: You can use HTML5  `<progress max="100" value="80"></progress>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML5 `progress` element

**HTML**

```
<progress max="100" value="80"></progress>
```

**CSS**

```
progress {
    height: 16px;
    width: 400px;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    border-radius: 24px;
    background: #fff;
    border: solid 2px #e5e5e5;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
    height: 16px;
    background: #37CC7D;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
    height: 16px;
    background: #37CC7D;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
progress::-moz-progress-bar {
    height: 16px;
    background: #37CC7D;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Major modern browsers will run `progress` element - [CANIUSE](http://caniuse.com/#search=progress)

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/fbjz2ofe/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
  aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
    <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try this code. this is what I used for my progress bar.